# Database table and column names as variables in code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-injection

I'm writing a CMS. I had this idea to have table and column names as variables. For example typical query would look like

```
" SELECT * FROM $DB_NEWS[table] WHERE $DB_NEWS[cat_id] = ? "
```

instead of

```
"SELECT * FROM news WHERE cat_id = ? "
```

And for each table I have an array for example I can set `$DB_USERS[table] = "sdfgdsgh"`
So if someone could somehow do an sql injection, he wouldn't know what's the name of users table, would he? Or is it totally useless security-wise ?

Even if it is, I'm starting to think it's not worth it. The code is less readable because of it. For example I have something like this in my code: `$result[$DB_USERS['username']]` 
looks terrible, doesn't it?

What do you think? I'm using PDO  and prepared statements everywhere  where is any user input (emulate prepares: false).
I'm thinking maybe I would just left table names as variables and columns would be normal.

Comment: If you use prepared statements you're reasonably secure against sql injections. If you write completely crap queries however ... that's another matter entirely. But I would advise against strange names (Makes debugging a pain in the *** too).

Comment: i see nothing wrong setting the table name even table fields name into a variable and reuse it over and over again. I think it is way better because you can change a table name only once if you ever come across changing the database table name. Also this is what most MVC do.

Comment: Depends on whether this code will be reused for a number of tables. If it will always call "news" in the end, there is no point in obscuring things.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will just stick with table names as variables. @EWit What do you mean by writing crap queries? Some examples?

Comment: @Kox if you write a query that returns "any" users info without verifying who the user is. No matter how good and prepared the query is. A malicious user may still be able to replace the ID with that of another user and get their data. If you use a `LIKE` expression users may still "inject" wildcard searches etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I don't have such vulnerabilities.